# DTO not working when used in service nestJS

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have a DTO like

```
export class CreatePlotDTO {
  @IsNumber()
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsOptional()
  area: number;

  @IsNumber()
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsOptional()
  ownerID: number;

}
```

and a create method
UPDATE: this is in the plotService and accepting the dto above

```
async createPlot(plot: CreatePlotDTO) {
  return this.plotModel.create(plot)
}
```

This has been working for the longest time but now is failing with this error

```
Argument of type 'CreatePlotDTO' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreationAttributes<Plot>'.
      Type 'CreatePlotDTO' is not assignable to type 'Omit<any, string>'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'CreatePlotDTO'.
```

I suspect the issue is with either "sequelize": "^6.16.2" or "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.3".
Any ideas to resolve this?

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: when trying to create a build or running tests.

Comment: Where in the code, not when.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is happening in all services that are implementing a create method. I am using sequelize with postgres. All my create methods in the different services accept a dto. When I try to create an object, run tests or run the build I get the error above. This was all working until maybe a week ago. Hopefully this is more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening to me also with the same versions ("sequelize": "^6.16.2" or "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.3"). I suspect there's something going on with one of those two, but as a workaround, I did something like the following:

1. Define your model like this:

```
@Table
export class Plot extends Model<Plot> {
    ...
}
```

(notice the `<Plot>` part).

2. Cast your DTO instance into the actual model type:

```
async createPlot(plot: CreatePlotDTO) {
    return this.plotModel.create(plot as Plot)
}
```

(notice the `as Plot` part).

Comment: surprisingly, doing something like export class Plot extends Model<Plot> on all the models resolved the issue as well. Thanks